# How to use liferay inbuilt email templates programatically?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6.2

In my liferay application I am adding application users by using Expando programatically and not using liferay default User signup.
Now I want to send credentials to user to his email address using liferay default templates available from Control Panel - Portal Setting - Email Templates.

How can I trigger email using this liferay inbuilt template?
Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Liferay uses template files(.tmpl) files to manage Email templates.
As per the Liferay Source,for User creation,given snippet is used to send out mail to users.

```
String body = PrefsPropsUtil.getContent(
            user.getCompanyId(), PropsKeys.ADMIN_EMAIL_USER_ADDED_BODY);

SubscriptionSender subscriptionSender = new SubscriptionSender();

    subscriptionSender.setBody(body);
    subscriptionSender.setCompanyId(user.getCompanyId());
    subscriptionSender.setContextAttributes(
        "[$USER_ID$]", user.getUserId(), "[$USER_PASSWORD$]", password,
        "[$USER_SCREENNAME$]", user.getScreenName());
    subscriptionSender.setFrom(fromAddress, fromName);
    subscriptionSender.setHtmlFormat(true);
    subscriptionSender.setMailId(
        "user", user.getUserId(), System.currentTimeMillis(),
        PwdGenerator.getPassword());
    subscriptionSender.setServiceContext(serviceContext);
    subscriptionSender.setSubject(subject);
    subscriptionSender.setUserId(user.getUserId());

    subscriptionSender.addRuntimeSubscribers(toAddress, toName);

    subscriptionSender.flushNotificationsAsync();
```

This is part of service impl class UserLocalServiceImpl.
Here "PropsKeys.ADMIN_EMAIL_USER_ADDED_BODY" is the path of the template for body content(default used by liferay).You can populate your custom data in the provided template.

Edit:
After you perform your custom logic,you can directly call

```
UserLocalServiceUtil.sendPassword(
            long companyId, String emailAddress, String fromName,
            String fromAddress, String subject, String body,
            ServiceContext serviceContext)
```

method directly from custom class,which will take care of using liferay template as well as password management.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I need to send user's password also, from where can I get user's password?

Comment: Try using user.getPassword() for that

Comment: user.getPassword() gives me encrypted password which cannot be decrypted. So that's not useful.

Comment: @LalitJawale Updated my answer!

Comment: Thanks for you time, but still it is using liferay's "Reset Password Template" which does not have password parameter.

Comment: If you are able to get the password,you can simply replace body key with ADMIN_EMAIL_USER_ADDED_BODY and make sure to populate the correct parameters as per the template

Comment: I am getting password but it is in encrypted format, So can you please tell me how can I decrypt it to send it as a parameter.

Comment: @LalitJawale as per the Edited answer,could you try directly using sendPassword method for email(containing password) after you perform your custom logic to add expando field

Comment: Sorry but my intention behind this scenario is to send user credentials to user at any time and not as soon as the user is added. So later I will not have that user's password with me to send it to email. Biggest hurdle is to have user password in PLAIN TEXT to send it to user.

Comment: As per to the best of my knowledge,due to security reasons,to not allow even developers have access to the user password,user password is not available as plain text.Even we had faced this hurdle some time back,but I guess with a clear business case,sending password should not be an option.Rather,the user should use  reset/Forgot password view.